# Warning: simplexml_load_string (Magento Error)

Tags: php, magento, simplexml

Im Facing the following errors since evening on my website (Please help):-

```
2016-07-13T16:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag allowed_methods line 143  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag fedex line 134  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag carriers line 106  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag default line 98  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 28  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag allowed_methods line 143  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag fedex line 134  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag carriers line 106  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag default line 98  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-07-13T16:10:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 143: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 28  in /home/digi/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

My Config file is shared below :-

```
    }
    if (is_null($newChecksum)) {
        return true;
    }
    $cachedChecksum = $this->getCache()->load($this->getCacheChecksumId());
    return $newChecksum===false && $cachedChecksum===false || $newChecksum===$cachedChecksum;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function loadCache()
{
    if (!$this->validateCacheChecksum()) {
        return false;
    }

    $xmlString = $this->_loadCache($this->getCacheId());
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, $this->_elementClass);
    if ($xml) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        $this->setCacheSaved(true);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param array $tags
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Config
 */
public function saveCache($tags=null)
{
    if ($this->getCacheSaved()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (false===$this->getCacheChecksum()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (is_null($tags)) {
        $tags = $this->_cacheTags;
    }

    if (!is_null($this->getCacheChecksum())) {
        $this->_saveCache($this->getCacheChecksum(), $this->getCacheChecksumId(), $tags, $this->getCacheLifetime());
    }

    $xmlString = $this->getXmlString();
    $this->_saveCache($xmlString, $this->getCacheId(), $tags, $this->getCacheLifetime());

    $this->setCacheSaved(true);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Return Xml of node as string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getXmlString()
{
    return $this->getNode()->asNiceXml('', false);
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Config
 */
public function removeCache()
{
    $this->_removeCache($this->getCacheId());
    $this->_removeCache($this->getCacheChecksumId());
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _loadCache($id)
{
    return $this->getCache()->load($id);
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @param string $id
 * @param array $tags
 * @param int|boolean $lifetime
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags=array(), $lifetime=false)
{
    return $this->getCache()->save($data, $id, $tags, $lifetime);
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @todo check this, as there are no caches that implement remove() method
 * @param string $id
 * @return unknown
 */
protected function _removeCache($id)
{
    return $this->getCache()->remove($id);
}

/**
 * Imports XML file
 *
 * @param string $filePath
 * @return boolean
 */
public function loadFile($filePath)
{
    if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
        //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
        return false;
    }

    $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
    return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
}

/**
 * Imports XML string
 *
 * @param  string $string
 * @return boolean
 */
public function loadString($string)
{
    if (is_string($string)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);

        if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
            $this->_xml = $xml;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Imports DOM node
 *
 * @param DOMNode $dom
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Element
 */
public function loadDom($dom)
{
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom, $this->_elementClass);

    if ($xml) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Create node by $path and set its value.
 *
 * @param string $path separated by slashes
 * @param string $value
 * @param boolean $overwrite
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Config
 */
public function setNode($path, $value, $overwrite=true)
{
    $xml = $this->_xml->setNode($path, $value, $overwrite);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Process configuration xml
 *
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Config
 */
public function applyExtends()
{
    $targets = $this->getXpath($this->_xpathExtends);
    if (!$targets) {
        return $this;
    }

    foreach ($targets as $target) {
        $sources = $this->getXpath((string)$target['extends']);
        if ($sources) {
            foreach ($sources as $source) {
                $target->extend($source);
            }
        } else {
            #echo "Not found extend: ".(string)$target['extends'];
        }
        #unset($target['extends']);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Stub method for processing file data right after loading the file text
 *
 * @param string $text
 * @return string
 */
public function processFileData($text)
{
    return $text;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Config $config
 * @param boolean $overwrite
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Config
 */
public function extend(Varien_Simplexml_Config $config, $overwrite=true)
{
    $this->getNode()->extend($config->getNode(), $overwrite);
    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably a malformed XML (missing tag for example...). Can you share the XML that you are trying to parse ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick update. But This came automatically, I did not tried to change or update anything. The site was running perfectly fine till afternoon and then in the evening there was some errors which on checking appeared some config errors. Can you help.

Comment: Also, the Config file that was in the simplexml folder has been shared above.

Comment: Hi, you need to inspect the xml file that was being parse. From the tags casuing the error, I suspect that you recently installed a new shipping method/module.